# How to get in catch method in Fetch API when there is no internet?

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch

I am using Fetch API for requests and I want to  handle an error when internet is disabled. But I didn't get any response in THEN function and no error message in  CATCH function. How can I handle this issue. I am trying do thid in React Native. Thank you before hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the **[`NetInfo`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html)** API available with React Native. You should be able to use the [isConnected](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html#isconnected) method to check if it's connected to the internet before making a request.

```
import {NetInfo} from 'react-native'

NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
  console.log('First, is ' + (isConnected ? 'online' : 'offline'));
  if (isConnected) {
    fetch(...)
  }
});
```

I was able to replicate the `catch` never getting called when the WiFi is off. Implementing a solution like this to manually throw an error if the request never returns could be a way around this. [See this discussion on handling Timeouts with Fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/175).

```
let test = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let id = setTimeout(() => reject('Timeout'),3000)
    fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/')
      .then(res => {
        resolve(res)
        clearTimeout(id)
       })
       .catch(err => {
         reject(err)
         clearTimeout(id)
      })
   })
}
test()
  .then(() => console.log('************Success'))
  .catch(() => console.warn('*************Error'))
```

Comment: Brad , thank you for response. I have already used NetInfo. I thought that i must handle this situation in catch method. Your solution is helpful but unfortunately isConnected always return False. I use NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener instead of NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().

Comment: Can you post an example of your call, and what the console logs?

Comment: I'm adding another answer that I think will solve your problem.